# Как сохранять данные для работы таймера при запуске программы?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2, qsettings

В `lineEdit` пользователь вводит какие-то данные, в `dataEdit` - дату до кого времени эти данные будут актуальны. После чего пользователь может закрыть программу.

Через некоторое время пользователь войдет в программу и нажмет на кнопку **`"Проверить срок окончания"`**, после чего если дата истекла появляется уведомление об этом, если нет то, уведомления то время не истекло.

Причем в программе несколько полей `dataEdit` и `lineEdit` и изменятся при иссечение  времени должна только та строчка, время которой истекло. 
Как такое реализовать?

код **.ui**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>480</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
      <property name="title">
       <string>GroupBox</string>
      </property>
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
         <item row="0" column="1">
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Дата окончания</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="0" column="0">
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Информация</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="4" column="0">
          <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_4"/>
         </item>
         <item row="1" column="1">
          <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit"/>
         </item>
         <item row="3" column="1">
          <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_3">
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true">QDateEdit{
Width: 200px;
Heigth: 50px;
}</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="4" column="1">
          <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_4"/>
         </item>
         <item row="2" column="1">
          <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_2"/>
         </item>
         <item row="1" column="0">
          <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
         </item>
         <item row="2" column="0">
          <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2"/>
         </item>
         <item row="3" column="0">
          <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_3"/>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="0">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Загрузить данные</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="3" column="0">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Проверить срок окончания</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>640</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Класс `QSettings` обеспечивает постоянные настройки приложения, не зависящие от платформы.

Comment: @S.Nick можете привести пример с данным классом?

Comment: хорошо, я посмотрю чем вам помочь.

Comment: Просто сохраните нужные данный в текстовый файл, когда пользователь хочет "Проверить срок окончания", просто выводите данные из этого файла

Comment: @zankorobos не все так просто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Класс **`QSettings`** обеспечивает постоянные настройки приложения,
> не зависящие от платформы.
>
> Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html

**`QSettings`** - это абстракция этих технологий, позволяющая сохранять
и восстанавливать настройки приложения переносимым способом.
Он также поддерживает настраиваемые форматы хранения.

Я немного подправил ваш **`.ui`**. 
Кнопка 'Загрузить данные' вам не нужна,
все что нужно будет сохранено по закрытию приложения.

Обратите внимание, чтобы все корректно работало:

1.Все объекты должны иметь `objectName`.

2.В строке `lineEdit` и `dateEdit` имена объектов должны соответствовать
следующим правилам:

- для первой строки `'lineEdit_1'` <---> `'dateEdit_1'`
- для второй строки `'lineEdit_2'` <---> `'dateEdit_2'`
- и т.д.

---

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QDateTime, QDate
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config_q1329659.ini'    # !!! сюда будем сохранять                       


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        loadUi("q1329659.ui", self)

        self._date = QDate.currentDate()
        self.listLineEdit = self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QLineEdit)
        self.listDateEdit = self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QDateEdit)

        self.load_settings()
        
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.check_date)

    def check_date(self):
        self.x_y()
        listLineEdit = self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QLineEdit)
        _dict = {}
        for lineEdit in listLineEdit:
            obj = lineEdit.objectName()
            if obj[0:9] == 'lineEdit_':
                key = obj[9:]                     #  lineEdit_3 --> '3'      
                _dict[key] = lineEdit.text()
        #print(_dict)    
    
        listDateEdit = self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QDateEdit)
        for dateEdit in listDateEdit:
            if self._date >= dateEdit.date():
                key = dateEdit.objectName()[9:]
                msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(self)
                msgBox.setWindowTitle("ВНИМАНИЕ")
                msgBox.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Warning)
                msgBox.setText(
                    'Пришло время, делайте что-нибудь!<br>'
                    f'Дата окончания: {dateEdit.date().toString("dd:MM:yyyy")}<br>'
                    f'Информация    : {_dict[key]}<br>'
                )
                msgBox.move(self.x, self.y)
                self.y += 150
                msgBox.show()

    def x_y(self):                                    
        self.x = self.pos().x() + 350
        self.y = self.pos().y()

    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue('Geometry',    self.saveGeometry())
        settings.setValue('WindowState', self.saveState())

        for lineEdit in self.listLineEdit:
            obj = lineEdit.objectName()
            settings.setValue(obj,  lineEdit.text())

        for dateEdit in self.listDateEdit:
            obj = dateEdit.objectName()
            settings.setValue(obj, dateEdit.date())
            
    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)   
        geometry = settings.value('Geometry')
        if geometry:
            self.restoreGeometry(geometry)
        state = settings.value('WindowState')
        if state:
            self.restoreState(state)

        for lineEdit in self.listLineEdit:
            obj = lineEdit.objectName()
            lineEdit.setText(settings.value(obj, ""))
        
        for dateEdit in self.listDateEdit:
            obj = dateEdit.objectName()
            _date = settings.value(obj, QDate.currentDate())
            dateEdit.setDate(_date)

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        self.save_settings()
        super().closeEvent(e)
     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 10))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1329659.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>350</width>
    <height>464</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
      <property name="title">
       <string>GroupBox</string>
      </property>
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
         <item row="0" column="1">
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Дата окончания</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="0" column="0">
          <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
           <property name="text">
            <string>Информация</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="4" column="0">
          <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_4"/>
         </item>
         <item row="1" column="1">
          <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_1">
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>100</width>
             <height>16777215</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="3" column="1">
          <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_3">
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>100</width>
             <height>16777215</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="styleSheet">
            <string notr="true"/>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="4" column="1">
          <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_4">
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>100</width>
             <height>16777215</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="2" column="1">
          <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_2">
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>100</width>
             <height>16777215</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="1" column="0">
          <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_1"/>
         </item>
         <item row="2" column="0">
          <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2"/>
         </item>
         <item row="3" column="0">
          <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_3"/>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>20</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="0">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Проверить срок окончания</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>350</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можете расписать основные модули для работы с сохранением данных?

Comment: @АндрейАлександров с начало вам нужно изучить то что предоставлено по ссылке. Также проработать некоторые посты по данной тематике https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+QSettings , а затем спросите, что конкретно вам не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Сохранять timestamp в каком либо файле

```
>>> from time import time
>>> time()
1631954517.858017
```

И потом сравнивать с меткой времени, которой тебе нужна

Comment: в каком конкретно файле сохранять данные? Явно ведь не в txt.

Comment: Если программа не сильно требует защиты, то можно даже и в txt, а так json,ini и множество других форматов текстовых файлов есть, выбирай

Comment: @SKISTE Тогда, может, лучше в базе данных хранить, чем в файле txt и т. д. ?

Comment: @Tehnorobot вот я и не знаю. Я могу записать данные в txt. Но, это как мне кажется неправильное решение?

Comment: @АндрейАлександров лучше создайте базу данных, это будет намного лучше, чем хранить в файле txt. Это, также, будет отличной практикой.

Comment: @Tehnorobot можете привести пример кода(или ссылку на статью) как создать базу данных.

Comment: @АндрейАлександров база данных обычно создается не из кода. Из кода вы просто к ней подключаетесь.

Comment: @АндрейАлександров оформлю в качестве ответа

Comment: @Tehnorobot понял. Если можете то напишите пример. Но, эти данные сохраняются только на одном пк и больше ни куда не идут.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете создать базу данных для хранения, изменения и удаления информации, а также для получения данных из базы. Это можно сделать вручную, а можно через `python`. Например, вы  можете воспользоваться библиотеками `sqlite3`, `MySQL` и т. д.

Пример записи через `sqlite3`:

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('shows.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Shows
              (Title TEXT, Director TEXT, Year INT)''')

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

После запуска файла вы увидите, что в вашем текущем каталоге проекта создан один файл с именем  shows.db. Это файл базы данных SQLite, созданный Python.
Подробнее вы также можете посмотреть [здесь](https://pythonru-com.turbopages.org/pythonru.com/s/osnovy/sqlite-v-python)

Я же для создания базы данных вручную использую программу `sqlitestudio`.

Comment: @АндрейАлександров у вас будет создан файл базы данных. Вы можете его переносить вручную, сохранить на сервере, защитить от проникновения в файл и т. д.

Comment: Вы можете погуглить и найти подробную инфу. Также посмотрите здесь: https://searchinform.ru/services/outsource-ib/zaschita-informatsii/bezopasnost-baz-dannykh/zaschita-baz-dannykh/bezopasnost-baz-dannykh-mysql/